# How can I get CollectionViewCell content height based on content size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, collectionview

I have few `CollectionViewCell` in my `CollectionView`. I need to adjust selected `CollectionViewCell` height after click on button. Please help.

```
   - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (indexPath.section == 2) 
        {

            CGFloat h = self.collectionView.contentSize.height;


            if (isExpandedAboutUs && indexPath.row == 0)
            {
                return CGSizeMake(ScreenW, h); 
            }

            return CGSizeMake(ScreenW, 100);
        }
    }
```

`self.collectionView.contentSize.height` will return `CollectionView` height. What I need is selected cell content size.

Comment: do you want to resize the cell or get the height of the cell?

Comment: Does each selected cell has different height?

Comment: sizeForItemAtIndexPath returns the size for cell that you want your cell to take. Do u want the size of cell in this method only?

Comment: @raki, yes, you are right.

Comment: @ShamimHossain, yes, so far I can make it collapse and expand. But I need to cater content size height when i click on expand.

Comment: @Van, I want the contentsize for this cell only.

Comment: @Henry got it but the question is in which method?

Comment: @Van, sorry im not too sure, as long as can make it works. As per what I wrote on top, I plan to get the value and apply in collectionView layout.

Comment: @Van, if sizeForItemAtIndexPath can get the cell contentsize, mind to share with me your code? Thanks!

Comment: @Henry We use sizeForItemAtIndexPath to decide the content size for cell I.e. the size for cell at given indexPath, we can not get the size of cell in this method it will be completely opposite to purpose of method. And this method gets called before the creation of cell, so anyhow cell isn't available for you at this point.

Comment: @Henry let me know if you are still unclear about the concept. would love to help in all possible ways

Comment: @Van, thanks for your prompt reply. My case actually is to reload the cell after click on the button. Everything working fine now but the only problem is how to get the contentsize for selected cell.

Comment: what do you want to do with content size? sorry but can you elaborate bit more so I can get the clear idea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174411/discussion-between-van-and-henry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with below code on selection of cell:

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    let contentSize = cell?.contentView.bounds.size
    print(contentSize)
}
```

if you want to get size from another method then you may need to find the cell selected index path and pass index path accordingly. like:

```
func yourMethod() {
    let selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)  //get your indexpath here
    let cell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
    let contentSize = cell?.contentView.bounds.size
    print(contentSize)
}
```

As per print statements, the values you get for contentSize is the same size as the size you return in sizeForItemAtIndexPath method.